# Passing $this to function

Tags: php, oop

In Javascript there is [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), that partially, but resolves to `call_user_func()` and `call_user_func_array()` in PHP.

Now, the difference here is that we can pass a variable with `call()` and `apply()` to be used as `this` within the function scope.

Can I achieve something like this with PHP?

### Update:

In Javascript:

```
var x = function(passed)
{
    return { dis : this, passd : passed };
};

console.log(x(44)); // window, 44

console.log(x.call(25, 44)); // 25, 44
```

`.call()` first parameter within the function scope, becomes `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP manual for **Callbacks**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

Example below:

```
// Type 3: Object method call
$obj = new MyClass();
call_user_func(array($obj, 'myCallbackMethod'));
```

Comment: See update. It's not about calling, it's about giving the called function explicit `$this`.

Comment: @psycketom Ok. The fact is that PHP does not allow `$this` outside class context. It throws a fatal error *Using $this when not in object context*, if I remember well.

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP5.4, it is possible to bind objects to Closures that'd act as `$this`.

Reference: http://lv.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php

Code:

```
<?php

$object = new StdClass;

$closure = function($a)
{
    $this->a = $a;

    return $this;
};

// Here, we bind it.
$closure = $closure->bindTo($object);

// Tests.
$out = $closure('this is "a"')->a;

var_dump($object, $out);
```

Voila! Full `$this` support in PHP. Though, it will only work with closures.

Comment: And this still rocks today, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could try passing it by reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

```
function Example (&$obj) {
    $obj->callFunction();
}
```

Comment: does not work, I get `Using $this when not in object context`, I tried to access a protected variable, maybe thats why?

Comment: no need to pass an object by reference because objects are default passed by reference